# Android ~ Remap then Use Hardware Buttons During Sleep / Locked

Tags: android, ios, button, hardware, remap

I own a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (Android 4.4.2).  **Can the following be developed under Android or iOS for a root or unrooted phone, perhaps using Xposed?**

Is it possible to remap any or all hardware buttons (eg.  Volume, Home, Power, Menu, Back) so that it can launch another app or even have that other app perform a particular function within it, all the while the screen is black (sleep, locked) ??

Im looking for an app (or will be happy to develop one) that will allow me to double tap my POWER or VOLUME and it quickly launches my favorite camera app then automatically have it take a photo snapshot (or whatever i have it set up to do within that app).    This would save me from having to unlock the phone, launch the app, then press the snapshot button.  A time saver.

Comment: On Android you can use a WakefulBroadcastReceiver with intents to do that...